# jQuery index of element within <body>

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out a way of finding the index of an element within `<body>`of a document. So far I have only been able to find the index of an element within the  **whole document** using this code:

```
$('div.css').click(function () {    
var mdivIndex;
mdivIndex = $(this).index('*');
console.log(mdivIndex);
});​
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fWhEK/1/)

To find the index within `<body>` do I have to use index() withour the asterisk?

Hopefully you can help me.
And once I find the index I assume that to select the element with that index I have to use:

```
$('body').eq(mdivIndex)...
```

Right?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `div.css` element is a direct child of the body, then all you need is:

```
mdivIndex = $(this).index();
```

---

To then select that element with that index, you'll use this:

```
$('body > *').eq(mdivIndex);
```

Or for better performance, you could use this:

```
$('body > :nth-child(' + (mdivIndex + 1) + ')');
```